# How can I get Process.MainWindowHandle that was minimized via SetWindowVisualState without storing the IntPtr?

Tags: c#, windows, window-handles

I am trying to make a program where it detects other window, minimize the window for a small duration of time, then make the same window normal from yet another program.

Minimizing is very easy (in order to make the code concise, I do not have error handling):

```
var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyTargetWindow").GetFirstOrDefault();
var elem = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
var pattern = elem.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern) as WindowPattern;
pattern.SetWindowVisualState(WindowVisualState.Minimized);
```

Now I want to make the window normal size again from another program.

At this point, if I store `p.MainWindowHandle` and re-use it, I do not have any issue.

However, if I DO NOT, and if I attempt to run following similar code to make the window normal, I will get InvalidOperationException when `GetCurrentPattern` is called. (I understand that the new handle does not support Pattern)

```
var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyTargetWindow").GetFirstOrDefault();
var elem = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
var pattern = elem.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern) as WindowPattern; // InvalidOperationException
pattern.SetWindowVisualState(WindowVisualState.Normal);
```

The cause is simple, `p.MainWindowHandle` from second code, is different from the original window.

Question is Why is the `p.MainWindowHandle` different?

**Ultimately, how can I re-retrieve the same handle without storing the handle in variable**

EDIT :

If the IntPtr storage is mandatory, I have no choice but to store it as string out on disk then re-retrieve it via new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32) and I am hoping there would be some other solution.

EDIT2 :

Storing IntPtr continues to have issue for me. Ultimately, I can store it to registry and read it, but I would have to keep track of when the handle was stored to registry as well. It is getting more complicated than I desire.

**I really really wish there is way to not store IntPtr and still find out the correct handle.**

Answer (score 2):

"The main window is the window opened by the process that currently has the focus (the TopLevel form)." but a minimized window can't have the focus anymore.

Save the `IntPtr` and P/Invoke [`ShowWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) on it. A much simpler proposition; no point in messing with automation, etc. when you can do it with that you have already.

The reason I'm not recommending something like re-implement the entire "find window handle" thing in native code is it won't be stable as the other process can create/destroy windows between the times so you won't reliably grab the same window again no matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If the IntPtr storage is mandatory, I have no choice but to store it as string out on disk then re-retrieve it via new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32) :( I was hoping I can avoid that

Comment: @ShinT: If you're storing window handles to disk you need to refactor in larger chunks until you don't need to do that.

Comment: would you mind clarifying what you mean by "refactor in larger chunk"?

Comment: @ShinT: Push the change upwards until you find something that's memory resident for the duration.

Comment: I now get what you mean. I will definitely do that. Long story short, this is part of installer's custom action C# code, so I would not have to store it in hdd but I would still have to rely on underlying installer's variable to store the string and convert it. I was hoping I did not have to do that.

Comment: @ShinT: Ah yes installer variable's a better choice; but perchance you can come up with something wild. Note that you really should use a 64 bit type for IntPtr -> string conversions in case somebody changes the project declaration from force 32 bit to any CPU.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not the path I can take. In a way, I have to control the visibility of the parent window from modal window. (msi window to bundle window relation). If I store the handle in registry, this can be handled, but I would have to store when the registry was generated. I really really wish I could find out the `IntPtr` on the fly.

Comment: @ShinT: The more I think about it the more I think that window manipulation from within an MSI is fraught with peril. You might not be on the correct session.

Comment: Definitely agree. "Correct way of doing things" are making custom BA, include all the windows in a single window, so that we do not have to consider hiding nor showing depending on installation state. But I am not granted time to do the right thing :( Ending up needing to hack things...